# Why can't I access Area51 from the Stack Exchange App?

Tags: support, ios-app

I use the iPhone app and I am really happy with it. However, Area51 is not listed in the list of sites to browse. Is there any way to access Area51.stackexchange.com from the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very much the same way that you can't access stackexchange.com from the mobile app - and for the same reason:

Both Area51 and stackexchange.com are not Q&A sites - they are very different beasts and share little with what the Q&A sites are for and how they operate. As such, integrating them into the mobile apps would take a lot of effort for relatively little benefit, given other things that we would rather spend developer time on.

tl;dr

Area51 is not on the mobile app because adding it is not currently a priority.